# How to send logs from fluentd and other logs related to pods to stackdriver monitoring dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine

I have to send the logs of pods and other events related to pods like the configmap updated, new pod scaled etc to the stackdriver monitoring dashboard of google cloud

Comment: i have also same query